# Cant find provider in router-outlet child

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I've built a service that I use to handle my http requests `ApiService` and I've added several files that wrap my http calls up nicely so I can process them (just for one, they all follow the same style `EmailApiService` and such and have the data passed back to my components as they need it.

The problem I'm having though is that in one of my components `ReportsComponent` that is controlled using the router, I get the error

`angular2.js?1460130081845:23877 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): No provider for EmailApiService! (ReportsComponent -> EmailApiService)`

The calls to the `EmailApiService` methods are in the constructor of `ReportsComponent`

When I add the same calls to my `ToolbarComponent` constructor (same way I'm doing it for the Reports) they work perfectly.

This leads me to believe that there is either something going wrong with how providers are passed to children that are added via the router, or I'm approaching it incorrectly.

app.component

```
import {ToolbarComponent} from './toolbar.component';
//pages
import {HomeComponent} from '../../home/components/home.component';
import {ReportsComponent} from '../..//reports/components/reports.component';
import {SignInComponent} from '../../signin/components/signin.component';
import {UserDetailsService} from '../../shared/services/user-details.service';
import {ApiService} from '../../shared/services/api.service';
import {EmailApiService} from '../../shared/services/email-api.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  viewProviders: [ApiService, EmailApiService, UserDetailsService],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ToolbarComponent]
})
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/', name: 'Sign In', component: SignInComponent, useAsDefault: true },
  { path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '/reports', name: 'Reports', component: ReportsComponent }
])

export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {}
}
```

app.html  (calls work on the `<toolbar>` but not the `<router-outlet>` (when i navigate to the reports page via the navbar)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <toolbar></toolbar>      
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

apiService

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  constructor(public http: Http,
              public userDetailService: UserDetailsService) {
  }

  request(type: RequestMethod, url: string, data: any, afterSuccess?: any) {
    ....
  }

  get(url: string, data: any, afterSuccess?: any) {
    ....
  }

  post(url: string, data: any, afterSuccess?: any) {
    ....
  }
}
```

emailapiService

```
@Injectable()
export class EmailApiService {

  token: string;
  service_provider_id: number;

  constructor(public apiService: ApiService,
              public userDetailService: UserDetailsService) {
    this.token = this.userDetailService.token;
    this.service_provider_id = this.apiService.service_provider_id;
  }

  emailExists() {
....
    return this.apiService.get('emails/email-address/exists');
  }


  emailSend()
....
    return this.apiService.post('emails/send');
  }
}
```

reportsComponent (doesnt work, throws missing provider)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'reports',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: './reports.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reports.component.css'],
  directives: []
})
export class ReportsComponent {
  constructor (public emailApiService: EmailApiService,
               public userDetailsService: UserDetailsService) {
    this.emailApiService.emailExists('test@gmail.com');
    this.emailApiService.emailSend('test', 'test@gmail.com');
    console.log(this.userDetailsService.loggedIn);
  }
}
```

toolbarComponent (works, calls succeed)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'toolbar',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: './toolbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toolbar.component.css'],
  directives: []
})
export class ToolbarComponent {
  constructor(public emailApiService: EmailApiService,
    public userDetailsService: UserDetailsService) {
    this.emailApiService.emailExists('test@gmail.com');
    this.emailApiService.emailSend('test', 'test@gmail.com');
    console.log(this.userDetailsService.loggedIn);
  }
}
```

One thing that I have looked at and have read around is adding apiService and emailApiService and UserDetailService to my bootstrap, but I feel that I shouldn't need to do this and I may have missed something as it works on the toolbar.

my bootstrap from my main.ts

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>' })
]);
```

Thanks in advance for taking the time to help me.

**edit**

I've tried changing `viewProviders` in the app component to `providers` and I still get the same issue.

I'm feeling that it may be correct to actually add these to by bootstraps provide, as they will be files that will be accessed across the app and used to store and share data.

Comment: change viewProviders with providers

Comment: when changing viewProviders to providers, i still get the same issue.
is there something else that i need to do also ?

Comment: Adding them to `boostrap()` if you want to share them with the whole app is fine. The Angular2 docs suggest to prefer `providers: [ ]` of the root component though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="container-fluid>
                           ^ missing closing "
  <toolbar></toolbar>      
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

otherwise can't reproduce [**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/1iYQuE?p=preview)

**edit**
Solution was found and talked about in the comments.
In the imports there is an extra /

```
import {ReportsComponent} from '../..//reports/components/reports.component';`
```

should be

```
import {ReportsComponent} from '../../reports/components/reports.component';`
```

Comment: when changing viewProviders to providers, i still get the same issue.
is there something else that i need to do also ?

Comment: can you create a plunker that allows to reproduce

Comment: Will do, I'll update the question with the link when  I have it working.

Comment: @NicholasTsaoucis See my updated answer with the working Plunker. If you still can't make it work then please try to reproduce it in a Plunker.

Comment: That missing " is missing from copying and pasting to here, so that wouldn't be it. I'll check our the plunker,

Comment: ok now just to make this even weirder, i copied and pasted the same constructor from my reports component to several of the others i have (signing, services, home, profile etc)
....they all work on those through the router perfectly.....then i hit the reports button and it fails...just on that page.
im so confused right now.

Comment: Do you have each service and component class in its own file or do you have several service and component classes in one file? Classes are not recognized when they are used, but declared only further down in the same file. Otherwise it's hard to help without a way to reproduce.

Comment: all in separate files, I'm looking through now to see if I can find what is different now that I know its working on other pages at the same level. Thanks for your help so far btw.

Comment: Also ensure you don't have cycles where dependencies are like A -> B -> C -> A

Comment: ive added that constructor to EVERY page in my app so far, and the only one that it fails on is the reports component....maybe i dont actually need this page in my app

Comment: WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOW I found the issue.
You know those times, where your missing a /.....or have to many /'s in a path when you import something, but you just never find it and it causes all kinds of problems?
yea it was one of those times.

Comment: Great, you figured it out! I run into such issues as well a few times when preparing Plunkers, but otherwise I develop only in Dart where such errors can't be overlooked.